# In-App Purchase fails and every time I get “Cannot connect to iTunes Store” with transaction status returns failed

Tags: swift, testing, in-app-purchase, in-app-subscription, revenuecat

We have been using RevenueCat for IAP auto-renewable subscriptions. We have properly followed RevenueCat integration guideline and able to successfully test IAP subscriptions through Sandbox testers for some devices and get failure for some devices. It’s kind of 50/50 scenario for IAP success/failure.

*Its not like Sandbox test users fail for IAP, in production build also IAP fails for many times.*

It would be helpful if you check code implementation we did for current app.

```
AppDelegate.swift

Purchases.debugLogsEnabled = true
Purchases.configure(withAPIKey: PURCHASE_APIKEY, appUserID: UIDevice.current.identifierForVendor?.uuidString)
```

`PremiumController` -> Which displays list of offerings from which user can select particular package and subscribe for the same.

```
var selectPackage: Purchases.Package?   // Selected package reference - the package which is selected by user



// Listing of all offerings which will be displayed to user and user will select an offering from this list
        Purchases.shared.offerings { [weak self] offerings, error in
            if let pack = offerings?.current?.availablePackages {
                self?.packages = pack
                
                for i in pack {
                    if i.packageType == .annual {
                        self?.selectPackage = i
                        break
                    }
                }
                
                self?.tableView.reloadData()        // Products listing
            }
        }



// Function to purchase the package
        if let package = selectPackage {
            purchasePackage(package)
        }


    func purchasePackage(_ package: Purchases.Package) {
        if Purchases.canMakePayments() {
            Purchases.shared.purchasePackage(package) { [weak self] transaction, purchaserInfo, error, userCancelled in
                if let error = error {
                    alertError(error.localizedDescription)      // Error alert will be displayed
                    return
                }
                
                if let info = purchaserInfo?.entitlements.all["powermove.pro"], info.isActive, let date = purchaserInfo?.latestExpirationDate {
                    Settings.expiresDateStr = date.toUTCSubscriptionString
                    
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Success", message: nil, preferredStyle: .alert)
                        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: { action in
                            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                                self?.back()        // this is kind of callback function which will be called to update UI
                            }
                        }))
                        self?.present(alert, animated: true)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

We have debugged the code and found out that when

```
storeKitWrapper:(RCStoreKitWrapper *)storeKitWrapper     updatedTransaction:(SKPaymentTransaction *)transaction
```

is called, `transaction.transactionState` is returned as `SKPaymentTransactionStateFailed`.

We are getting error -> **“Cannot connect to iTunes Store”**. Below are some log statements.

```
2020-10-19 18:06:40.657001+0530 Strong Consumer[37652:7035479] [Purchases] - DEBUG: GET /v1/subscribers/069A0745-1204-4079-8D7D-D14E95211998
2020-10-19 18:06:40.657370+0530 Strong Consumer[37652:7035479] [Purchases] - DEBUG: Offerings cache is stale, updating caches
2020-10-19 18:06:40.657607+0530 Strong Consumer[37652:7035479] [Purchases] - DEBUG: GET /v1/subscribers/069A0745-1204-4079-8D7D-D14E95211998/offerings
2020-10-19 18:06:40.663777+0530 Strong Consumer[37652:7035479] [Purchases] - DEBUG: PaymentQueue removedTransaction: monthly_5.99 AB64AECB-94AD-45CA-B836-65D0D6EC6D0C ((null) Error Domain=SKErrorDomain Code=0 "Cannot connect to iTunes Store" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Cannot connect to iTunes Store}) {
2020-10-19 18:06:40.664062+0530 Strong Consumer[37652:7035479] [Purchases] - INFO: Subscriber attributes synced successfully
```

Comment: I seems the main issue is a package missed on RevenueCat dashboard which I had to register then everything worked like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

From the logs, you're getting an `SKErrorUnknown` (code 0) from Apple. There's unfortunately nothing you can do on your end to resolve these in production. It's either a problem with the user's Apple account, or an internal problem with Apple.

Apple docs: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/skerrorcode/skerrorunknown

Answer (score 0):

I have also faced the same issue as well. it seems like builds with Development and Ad Hoc certificates are having this issue. I uploaded a build to TestFlight. and is working just fine.